# Does detect magic go through walls?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, skills, magic

I have a chest hidden behind a false mechanical wall and in that chest are magical items, would the player using detect magic be able to notice the items?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**It depends on what material the wall is made of.**

[Detect Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic/) can penetrate certain materials, but depending on the thickness and type of the material, the obstruction may block its path.

> The spell can penetrate barriers, but 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt blocks it.

So if the wall is either:

- Made of metal, and less than 1 inch in thickness, or
- Made of stone, and less than 1 foot in thickness, or
- Made of wood or dirt, and less than 3 feet in thickness, or
- Made of anything else, except for lead,

then the spell can detect what's behind the wall.

Comment: I suppose that lead padded chests could be quite common for certain uses... just don't put your potions there :)

Answer (score 2):

Depends how thick the false wall is and what it is made of. From the spell description:

> The spell can penetrate most barriers, but it is blocked by 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt.

Also, note from sage advice:

> Jeremy Crawford @JeremyECrawford
>
> Sensing a presence means you sense something is present, not its location. "Wait, magic is nearby . . ."

https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/01/15/would-allow-detect-magic-a-creature-under-the-effects-of-invisibility-spell/

Comment: Isn't that tweet specific to 5th Edition D&D, and so therefore of no relevance to Pathfinder?